# Volume of curved prism

Tags: volume

How can the volume of a square-crosssection prism that is curved with the following dimensions be calculated?

- inner $R$ radius
- with squared section area $a \cdot a = S$
- length is an arc of longitude $L$

[image]

Comment: Is the radius of curvature on the inside, the outside or the center of the prism?

Comment: @PrimeMover Inside, thanks for the attention

Comment: As long as  the "section" at different part of solid doesn't intersect and the locus of centroid is a regular enough curve, the volume is the area of section times the length of the locus of centroids. This works even if you twist the section around the centroid as it moves along the locus.

Comment: @achillehui This together with GoRza's answer is the perfect combination. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm... thinking about it, I missed a condition in previous comment, the section need to be perpendicular to the tangent vector of the locus of centroids for the formula to work (which holds in your case)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**HINT**

You can calculate the area of the basis (the "curved band") and then multiplicate by the high.

Comment: This question should not have been answered, @GoRza until the question is improved.

Comment: It actually answered my question @GoRza. Thankss!